# Apache Beam ReadFromSpanner decoding issue

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to run the following script in a GCP Dataflow pipeline.

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional
from apache_beam.io.gcp.spanner import *
from past.builtins import unicode
import logging

class ItemRow(NamedTuple):
    item_id: unicode


class LogResults(beam.DoFn):
  """Just log the results"""
  def process(self, element):
    logging.info("row: %s", element)
    yield element

class SpannerToSpannerAndBigQueryPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):
    """
    Runtime Parameters given during template execution
    path parameter is necessary for execution of pipeline
    """
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--SOURCE_SPANNER_PROJECT_ID', type=str, help='Source Spanner project ID',
            default='project_id')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--SOURCE_SPANNER_DATASET_ID', type=str, help='Source Spanner dataset ID',
            default='dataset_id')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--SOURCE_SPANNER_INSTANCE_ID', type=str, help='Source Spanner instance ID',
            default='instance_id')
        parser.add_argument(
            '--SOURCE_QUERY', type=str, help='SQL to run in Source Spanner Instance',
            required=True)


# Setup pipeline

def run():

    beam.coders.registry.register_coder(ItemRow, beam.coders.RowCoder)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    importer_options = pipeline_options.view_as(
        SpannerToSpannerAndBigQueryPipelineOptions)

    
    rows = (
        p
        | "Read from source Spanner" >> ReadFromSpanner(
            project_id=importer_options.SOURCE_SPANNER_PROJECT_ID,
            instance_id=importer_options.SOURCE_SPANNER_INSTANCE_ID,
            database_id=importer_options.SOURCE_SPANNER_DATASET_ID,
            row_type=ItemRow,
            sql='Select item_id from Items WHERE created_ts BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()',
            timestamp_bound_mode=TimestampBoundMode.MAX_STALENESS,
            staleness=3,
            time_unit=TimeUnit.HOURS,
        ).with_output_types(ItemRow)
    )

    rows | 'Log results' >> beam.ParDo(LogResults())

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

However, I've been running into issues for decoding the results obtained from Spanner. These are the output logs from my Dataflow job:

```
"An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 6665479626992209510 : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/inmemory.py", line 108, in __iter__
    yield self._source.coder.decode(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 468, in decode
    return self.get_impl().decode(encoded)
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 226, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.decode
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 228, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.decode
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 123, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/row_coder.py", line 215, in decode_from_stream
    is_null in zip(self.components, nulls)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/row_coder.py", line 215, in <genexpr>
    is_null in zip(self.components, nulls)))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 259, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 261, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 414, in decode
    return value.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 9: invalid start byte
"
```

I'm unsure as to how to solve this problem. I'm using this https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.spanner.html?highlight=spanner#module-apache_beam.io.gcp.spanner example as a starting point. The issue appears to be in decoding the results obtained from Spanner. There is little to no documentation on how to specify the schema for the Spanner table/tables I'm trying to query.

There is also an experimental IO module for Spanner which does not use the Java expansion module. Is it recommended to switch to the experimental version?

Thanks

Comment: The schema is declared in the "row_type" argument. In your case the ItemRow named tuple. Can you try changing the item_id type to int from unicode?

Comment: The actual id is a STRING<MAX> field in Cloud Spanner. Why would it be an int?

Comment: I was thinking that if your schema was an int in Spanner, then trying to read it out as unicode would create that error. But since your id is actually a string, something else is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can try to change the schema to bytes and see what it returns? That shouldn't incur a decoding so you can see what Beam thinks is the id.

Comment: Hi @Cubez, I've changed the item_id type to `bytes`, the runner only outputs the following line: `row: BeamSchema_0beb6e87_96a5_4128_a80c_78e1697e7674(item_id=b'')` 

I'm fairly sure this should not be the case. I've managed to read from Spanner using the experimental Spanner I/O module using the same credentials.

Comment: That's very weird. It looks like it's not parsing the proto into a Python object. Can you try moving the register_coder line out of the function call right before the `if __name__ == 'main'` line? Also, the row has an empty string item id. Do you have any null item IDs in your database?

Comment: No. It's the primary key in the relation.

Answer (score 0):

I could not run a pipeline using the `apache_beam.io.gcp.spanner` module so I ended up using the `apache_beam.io.gcp.experimental.spannerio` module instead.

Comment: Can you share your final working code using experimental? I'm stuck at same point